# Toggle Button doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 3 toggle buttons in my playstate as follows:

```
public void ShowIt()
        {
            HydroElectric ec = new HydroElectric();

            ec.t1Bool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (25, 55, 100, 50), ec.t1Bool, "Turbina 2 MW");

            ec.t2Bool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (25, 95, 100, 50), ec.t2Bool, "Turbina 3 MW");

            ec.t3Bool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (25, 135, 100, 50), ec.t3Bool, "Turbina 1 MW");

            GUI.Box (new Rect (Screen.width - 100, 60, 80, 25), ec.prod.ToString ());      // PRODUCED ENERGY  
         }
```

This buttons should change the value of `t1Bool`, `t2Bool` and `t3Bool` and those changes should be reflected in this script:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
namespace Assets.Code.PowerPlants
{
    public class HydroElectric
    {
        public bool t1Bool;
        public bool t2Bool;
        public bool t3Bool;

        public static int turbina1;
        int turbina2;
        int turbina3;

        public float prod;

        public HydroElectric ()
        {
         t1Bool = true;
         t2Bool = true;
         t3Bool = false;
         prod = 0f; 
        }

        public float HydroControlPanel ()
        {
            turbina1 = t1Bool ? 2 : 0;
            turbina2 = t2Bool ? 3 : 0;
            turbina3 = t3Bool ? 1 : 0;

            prod = turbina1 + turbina2 + turbina3;
            return prod;
        }
    }
}
```

I have no errors in the console but the toggle button simply does not work in play mode, like if the values are locked, I cannot check or uncheck the buttons, they just stay the way they start.

Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-creating `HydroElectric` every time GUI-related functions are called, obviously changes are not reflected and you get the behavior you said.

Move this line of code out of that function to somewhere else such as in the constructor and it will behave properly.

Comment: You are talking about this line? HydroElectric ec = new HydroElectric();

Comment: Yes, since it's a new object on every call, values are not changing and you get that confusing behavior when running your game :D